# Find matches in a card hand turns up slightly off results around 10% of the time

Tags: vb.net

This is my code which is supposed to compare the values in the array 'arrHands' which stores a hand of x cards (x = cardsDrawn) as singles where the integer part is the suit (1 to 4) and the decimal represents the card number ( .01 = 1 = Ace, etc).
  However around 1 in 10 times it runs it returns values that are off by one or two pairs. I know that this will happen when the hand contains a three-of-a-kind, as i haven't written the code for that yet, but it still doesn't make sense. if the value returned is wrong it is always higher than i expected.
here's the code:

```
  Dim numPairs As Integer = 0 
    Dim A As Integer = 1 
    Dim B As Integer = 1 

  'A and B represent the position in the array of the cards being compared

    For A = 1 To cardsDrawn 

        For B = 1 To cardsDrawn 
            If (A <> B) And (A < B) And (arrHand(A) <> 0) And (arrHand(B) <> 0) Then 
                 'The above line stops cards from being compared to each other, or to a card they have already been compared to.

                If (arrHand(A) - (Int(arrHand(A))) = (arrHand(B) - (Int(arrHand(B))))) Then 

    'the code above extracts the card number from the single that each card is stored as

                    numPairs += 1 
                    arrHand(A) = 0 
                    arrHand(B) = 0 
                End If 

            End If 
        Next 
    Next
```

Thanks for any help or ideas you may have.

Comment: If you're just gonna break if `A < B`, why not do something like `For A = 1 To cardsDrawn` `For B = A To cardsDrawn` (or `B = A + 1`, as appropriate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost always a bad idea to glue 2 pieces of information into one variable.  Classes make it easy to track the various datum for a card:

```
Public Class Card
    Private Shared Faces() As String = {"Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"}
    Private Shared Names() As String = {"Ace", "Deuce", ..."King"}

    Public Property Value As Int32
    Public Property Rank As Int32
    Public Property Suit As String
    Public Property Img As Image
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} of {1}", Names(Rank - 1), Suit)
    End Function
End Class
```

There is a `Value` and a `Rank` because a card always has the same rank, but depending on the game, the Value may change (e.g. Euchre and Baccarat).  A Deck class could use a `Stack(Of Card)` and a hand can be a `List(Of Card)` or an array depending on the game.

Given an array of 5 cards, ranking the hand for poker is simple with linq (and assuming Poker):

```
Dim pairs = cards.
    GroupBy(Function(v) v.Value,
            Function(key, values) New With {
                    Key .Rank = key,
                    Key .Count = values.Count()
                    }).
            OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.Count).
            ThenByDescending(Function(r) r.Rank).
            ToArray()
```

If `pairs.Count` is 4, there is Four of a Kind; likewise 2pair when `Count=2` and a pair when the count is one.  If `pairs(0).Count = 3` then you have trips.

If `pairs.Count = 2 AndAlso pairs(0).Count = 3`, then you have a FullHouse.  It is pretty simple to also do a Group on the suit to determine a flush, and put them in order to see if it is a Straight.

Do be sure to test hands from high to low:  you don't want to return 2 pair when it is really a Full House.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it didn't even occur to me to use classes, out of interest, do you have any idea why my original code didn't work? @Plutonix

Comment: Not sure - I would not dream of writing a card game with procedural code.  it might be `Int(arrHand(A)` - `Int` returns the integral portion of the value which is where you stored the suit

Comment: Another thing is that arrays start at element 0, yours starts evaluating with 1.

Comment: i  used the line "arrHand(counter) = cardCode" to populate the array. it followed the generation of the card and the conversion to the cardCode in my program. @codemonkeyliketab

Comment: For this: `Dim cardCode = 2 + 9 / 100` ie suit 2, card #9, `Int(cardCode)` is going to return 2.0 - your code is evaluating suits not the rank/value.  It probably can never return a no-pairs hi card value

Comment: (arrHand(A) - (Int(arrHand(A))) subtracts the integer part to leave the decimal, not the other way around @plutonix

Comment: @LucasParkins it was most likely due to floating point arithmetic... you can't store 0.1 (or 0.01) in base 10 exactly. If you compared the two numbers for "near equality" (against some epsilon) you probably wouldn't have seen your issue. That said I would never do it the way you were doing it... Classes exist for a reason.