# VB poker hand evaluator

Tags: vb.net

My class programming project is to create a program that allows you to input numbers and letters to specify a card number and suit (e.g. 2 and D = 2 of Diamonds).

This is what it will look like:
[Poker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLmKs.jpg)

This is the code I have so far:

```
Public Class frmPoker
    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        Dim cards(4) As Integer
        Dim suit(4) As String

        cards(0) = CInt(txtCard1.Text)
        cards(1) = CInt(txtCard2.Text)
        cards(2) = CInt(txtCard3.Text)
        cards(3) = CInt(txtCard4.Text)
        cards(4) = CInt(txtCard5.Text)

        Dim card = From item In cards
                   Select item
                   Distinct

        If card.Count = 4 Then
            txtDisplay.Text = "One Pair"
        ElseIf card.Count = 3 Then
            txtDisplay.Text = "Three of a kind"
        ElseIf card.Count = 2 Then
            txtDisplay.Text = "Four of a kind"
        End If

        suit(0) = txtSuit1.Text
        suit(1) = txtSuit2.Text
        suit(2) = txtSuit3.Text
        suit(3) = txtSuit4.Text
        suit(4) = txtSuit5.Text

        Dim suits = From item In suit
                    Select item
                    Distinct

        If suits.Count = 1 Then
            txtDisplay.Text = "Flush"
        End If
```

I'm not sure how to approach determining a full house and a straight flush. Also if there is, for example, two 2s and two 3s, the program will determine that is actually three of a kind.

Comment: [This might be of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38129686/1070452).  The key is to evaluate from high to low so that a FullHouse is not seen as trips or a pair

Comment: I am guessing some of that code is something you nicked from somewhere and not actually something covered in an intro class?

Comment: It is from class. The book goes over LINQ briefly. Unfortunately it doesn't do a good job of explaining things (at least to me).

Comment: Just use an array to count how many of each rank there are:  `For Each n As Int32 In cards : counts(n) += 1 : next`.  Then you just have to count the number of pairs, quads and trips to get the result for a bunch of hands.

Comment: Sorry, not understanding how to go about using/defining counts(n). I'm going to reread the chapter to see if there is something I missed. :/

Comment: Oh,  this is the best idea ever.  When you finished,  could you give me the download?  I would love to try out.

Comment: Thanks for your help Plutonix. If I could buy you a beer, I would, ha.

Comment: What is your actual question? You have made a bunch of statements, but have not actually asked a question, or explained where your *specific* problem is. You might want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use code you dont understand.  For example:

```
Dim card = From item In cards
           Select item
           Distinct
```

That will tell you the different cards in the hand but not how many of each. The hand `{2, 2, 3, 2, 3}` gives the same result as `{9, 10, 9, 9, 9}`.   In fact the result for trips `{3, 3, 3, 2, 7}` will be the same as for 2 pair `{3, 3, 2, 2, 7}`.  There isnt enough information there for what you want.

Here is an alternative (note: assumes a 5-card hand, and Aces Hi to start):

```
' dont use 0th; Ace=1 and 14
Dim counts(15) As Int32
' count how many of each rank:
For Each n As Int32 In cards
    counts(n) += 1      
Next
```

At the end, each element will tell you how many of each rank there is.  For instance `count(2)` may hold the value 3 indicating there are 3 Deuces.  Then iterate the array to evaluate:

```
Dim pairs As Int32 = 0
Dim trips As Int32 = 0
Dim quads As Int32 = 0
' count them:
For Each n As Int32 In counts
    If n = 2 Then pairs += 1
    If n = 3 Then trips += 1
    If n = 4 Then quads += 1
Next
Dim Aced = counts(14) > 0
```

That covers a lot of hands.  You also need to know if there is an Ace so you can later test for a Wheel ({A, 2, 3, 4, 5}).  Flushes come into play in 2 places, so just set a flag:

```
Dim Flushed = Suits(0) = Suits(1) AndAlso
              Suits(0) = Suits(2) AndAlso
              Suits(0) = Suits(3) AndAlso
              Suits(0) = Suits(4)
```

A Straight is harder to do since you have to check the order of an unordered set.  So first, put it in order an see if that sequence matches a manufactured one.  Some research needs to be left to you, but `Enumerable` will create the comparison range; test it using `Array.Intersect` or `.SequenceEqual` or just do something like the code for `Flushed`.

The Straight and Flush tests *can* be skipped if (pairs + trips + quads > 0), but they are pretty simple and just collecting all the metrics for the hand and doing a series of `If` tests at the end makes the code easier to debug.

Aces make it messy. If there is an Ace, you need to check for a Wheel: copy counts(14) to counts(1) and set counts(14) to zero.  Then sort and check the sequence again. After that, it is just a matter of evaluating those variables in order from high to low.  These exercises are left for the student.